# Inline list indented

Tags: html, css

I am developing on a 1280px wide screen and although the pics that I'm displaying only add up to 1264px the last one is not displaying inline and instead is being put in a new line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/indexCSS.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topPics">            
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="images/santa.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                </li>                
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="images/eyes.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="images/ladyBlue.jpg"/>            
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="images/andy.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>                        
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <span style="font-size: 30px; color: #fff; font-family: cursive;"> TEXT</span>
            <span style="color: #999"> |  TEXT</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    root { 
        display: block;
    }

    body{
        background: #0f0f0f;     
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    ul{     
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    li{    
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
        height: 100%; 

    }

    .topPics{
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%; 

    }

    .logo{
         margin-top: 10px;
         margin-bottom: 10px; 
         margin-left: 40px; 
         width: 100%
    }
```

Can anyone see whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming it is the standard `margin` and `padding` of the `ul` and `body` elements.

To remove these (they are automatically set by the browser), simply apply:

```
html, body {
    position: relative; /*A little addition*/
    padding: 0; /*Reset browser padding*/
    margin: 0; /*Reset browser margin*/
    height: 100%; /*sets the html/body height to 100% of the window height*/
}

ul {
    padding: 0; /*Reset ul padding*/
    margin: 0; /*Resets ul margin*/
    list-style: none; /*The bullets will look messed up w/o padding.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screen might be 1280px, but some of that space is taken by the border and scroll bar of your your browser, so you don't have 1280 pixels to draw on. Just try to set width:1280px on topPics to see the effect.

Comment: Nope still the same. Forgot to mention that there seems to be a margin on the left hand side of the page

Answer (score 0):

try use that simple trick to remove space between the LI

```
.topPics ul { 
   font-size: 0;  
   padding: 0; /* reset padding */
   margin: 0; /* reset margin */
}
```